# iniciar sesion de acuerdo al rol indicado

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, mvc

estoy creando un login en mvc asp.net y estoy usando sql server, en el cual dependiendo del rol va poder accerder al sistema, pero rol lo tengo en otra tabla llamada tiporol pero noce como llamar ese valor del rol dentro de usuarios ya que usuarios y rol estan relacionadas, pero al momento que yo mando llamar rol no me deja acceder a la vista que le corresponde solo me aparece llena todos los campos y esto es lo que tengo de mi codigo.

```
 [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Login(string usuario, string contraseña,string rol)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraseña) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rol))
            {
                var pass = Encrypt.Hash(contraseña);
               

                var user = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(e => e.numeroUsuario == usuario && e.contraseña == contraseña);
               var roles = db.TipoRols.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Roles == rol );


                if (roles.Roles == "administrador")
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(roles.Roles, true);
                    Session["nombre"] = user.nombre;
                    Session["apellidos"] = user.apellidos;
                    return RedirectToAction("IndexAdministrador", "Home");

                }
                else

            if (roles.Roles == "tecnico")
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(roles.Roles, true);
                    Session["nombre"] = user.nombre;
                    Session["apellidos"] = user.apellidos;
                    return RedirectToAction("IndexTecnico", "Home");

                }
 else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "No reconocemos tus datos" });

                }
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Llena todos los campos para poder iniciar secion" });

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu usuario tiene referencia a un rol

```
var rolUsuario = db.TipoRols.where(a => a.Id== user.idRol ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: bueno cuando ejecuto el comando me manda esto Login?message=Llena todos los campos para poder iniciar secion, asi que no esta podiendo acceder al sistema

Comment: ¿Qué error cometió el OP? ¿Cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo? No has dicho ni lo uno ni lo otro; esta respuesta es un hechizo Harry Potter: funciona (tal vez), nadie sabe porque, ni cómo  o cuando aplicarlo.